# Why hasn't Windows Update offered me Threshold 2 yet?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I'm using RTM Windows 10 Enterprise, which I clean installed from bare metal on 26th September this year.

Based in the UK, not in the Insider Ring.

WU hasn't offered me Threshold 2 yet - should I be concerned, or just more patient?

I've done a manual check-for-updates, and several recent reboots, it just says I'm up to date.

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I don't mind waiting, if it's simply a question of a staggered roll-out.  And though I'm aware that updates can be downloaded manually and installed, I was hoping to avoid this.

Specifically, I'm interested in whether my own settings can compromise my ability to receive Windows Updates.

In particular, I've:

- disabled all the data-slurping features in Cortana
- spent much of the last few weeks with UAC switched off.
- disabled `Updates from more than one place`.

I also have:

`Give me updates for other MS products` **selected**, and

`Defer updates` **not** selected.

Comment: download the VL ISO from MSDN or VL Portal, mount the ISO, run setup.exe and upgrade

Comment: Any answer we provide we amount to nothing more then, the update is being rolled out to everyone, Microsoft deemed it necessary not to roll it out to everyone at once.  There are dozens and dozens of technology news articles, about this update, that basically indicate its being rolled out.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll wait a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually (Dec 1st) I gave up waiting, and since I have a 1511 ISO, I updated using that.

Mounted the ISO, ran the setup, and ensured that `Keep Files and Settings` was selected when given the option.

As soon as the install completed and I'd rebooted, Windows Update straightaway started offering me updates again, including the Windows Defender ones which I'd been getting every day anyway, but more to the point, the cumulative updates were also coming through.

It doesn't explain why I didn't get it from Windows Update, but at least I'm getting updates again.

Comment: This particular update is handled different on Windows 10 Enterprise.    I must have not caught that factoid originallly